# jQuery toggle element class based on scroll percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the var num into a percentage instead of a number of pixels.
how can I do this?

I need this for my site:
http://www.sutanaryan.com/Tutorials/fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-CSS-and-jQuery/
But they work with pixels, and my website works with % (because autoscaling for example on a HD screen or a Full HD screen)

/* Dynamic top menu positioning
     *
     */

```
var num = 150 ; //number of pixels before modifying styles 150


$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});

//USE SCROLL WHEEL FOR THIS FIDDLE DEMO
```

Comment: depending on if your num is width or height you could do num/screen.width * 100 or num/screen.height * 100

Comment: with "$(window).scrollTop() > num" you will be then comparing pixels and percentage, which is kinda strange

Comment: everything has to be changed into percentages for navigation bar on my website because I work in my css also with %, for example my header width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me tell you this is a horrible solution. Listening to every scroll event and calling addClass() or removeClass() every time is expensive. // end preach

Here's the answer to your question anyway:

```
var baseHeight = $(window).height(); // for body, use $("body").height();
var num = .25; // this the percentage of vertical scroll

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() / baseHeight > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a better way maybe?

Comment: There are several ways to optimize/improve your script, depending on what kind of performance you're looking for. At least you should check `hasClass('fixed')` before adding or removing the class. Cache the `$('.menu')` object. Perhaps utilize `setTimeout()` to limit calls to this thing. And encapsulate the callback as a named function while you're at it.